# jQuery sort unordered list alphabetically and numerically based on inner element value(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Code as reference:

http://jsbin.com/aboca3/2/edit

In this example above (thank you SLaks) I am truncating long unordered lists and providing a toggle link to view the entire thing.

The issue, from a usability standpoint, is that as a full list, it is best sorted alphabetically, which will be the default sort order (the source order). As a short/truncated list, they are most usefully ordered by the magnitude these options will effect the results, in this case the number in the `<em>` element.

So working with the code I already have, I would like to re-order the list numerically by `<em>` element (highest to lowest), and then when the list is toggled, re-order it alphabetically/numerically based on toggle state.

I'm having a hell of a time trying to wrap this in to an associative array so I'd love a fresh perspective on how to handle this.

Thank you!

Comment: I can think of ways to do this, but I can see usability issues with this. User clicks to see more choices, and have to read the top 4 again because the order has changed. Or user clicks to see more choices, and does not notice the order has changed, so ignores what could possibly be a new top 4 results.

Comment: As much as I'm open to a healthy debate, I'm asking how to accomplish this, not if I should accomplish this. This will be presented along with alternative methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it for you: http://jsbin.com/aboca3/5/edit

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm after. There seems to be a bug though, or perhaps I did not explain properly.

When viewing only 5, only the first 5 items are sorted by em value, when I need all the facets sorted by em value and then truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Using petersendidit's code I was able to acheive exactly the result I was looking for. You can view it here:

http://jsbin.com/aboca3/7/edit